# Installing rpy or rpy2 on mac

Tags: python, r, installation, rpy2

I'm in the process of trying to install rpy or rpy2 on my Macbook so I can use R from python. Information about rpy can be found here: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/index.html

My problem is in the installation itself. I can't seem to make python recognize Rpy using import command: I keep getting the message "No module named rpy2". Does anyone know where I can find some step-by-step instructions on how to successfully install this? I have already installed both python and R, and both are working perfectly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try `easy_install rpy2`. You need to install [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) before that.

I took that from [here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/overview.html#easy-install-and-pip)

Answer (score 2):

I long gave up on these issues on my Mac. Since I installed OS Lion, I found that I needed to switch to [MacPorts](https://web.archive.org/web/20140821133357/https://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts) and then installing packages like RPy2 from [their repository](https://ports.macports.org/search/?q=Rpy2&name=on).

I know some people like to dig into the system and learn all the idiosyncrasies of the architecture and keep a vanilla install of python on their Mac. I find that i get problems like yours too frequently and they distract me from real work.

I just download the [MacPorts modules](https://web.archive.org/web/20200510115520/https://www.macports.org/ports.php) when I need them and get on with the problem at hand. Others say the same thing about [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/) but I have only worked with MacPorts and it makes installation of modules too easy. You may want to invest some time investigating if either of these solutions work for you.

Another approach to using package managers like MacPorts or HomeBrew is to use a [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) and install python and all related modules there. Again, not a solution I have tried directly, but a quick search will show you many endorsements for this approach to using a specific Python executable and packaging its modules In an isolated environment.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have pip installed on your mac, then life will be easy as:
sudo pip install rpy2

Answer (score -1):

If you want rpy it isn't on macport, at least a search of their packages only showed rpy2.  According to the rpy web site its in fink.  However at the moment fink is down so I can't verify this.  Which is irritating because I need rpy (not rpy2) because another package has a dependency on it.

I also tried pip to find rpy and it said no package, which is a shame because pip is great for python installs (provided I remember to use 'sudo' first.